# ClickableText() click offset: The resulting characters are not as expected, Why is that?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

For example, if you click on T in This, you might get an h.

```
val text = AnnotatedString("This is a very very very very very very very long text")
ClickableText(text,style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
        with(textLayoutResult) {
            val boundingBox = getBoundingBox(0)
            Log.d("offset", "topCenter: ${getOffsetForPosition(boundingBox.topLeft)}")
            Log.d("offset", "topCenter: ${getOffsetForPosition(boundingBox.topCenter)}")
            val offset = boundingBox.topCenter.copy(x = boundingBox.center.x+1)
            Log.d("offset", "topCenter x+1: ${getOffsetForPosition(offset)}")
        }
    }) { offset ->
    Log.d("ClickableText", "Clicked: ${text[offset]}")
}
```

onTextLayout:  (Why is that?)

```
D/offset: topLeft: 0
D/offset: topCenter: 0
D/offset: topCenter x+1: 1
```

Comment: what is your final goal? To know the word clicked or to handle different actions?

Comment: Sorry, I reedited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It feels to me after reading through the available methods that a lot of the features baked into `ClickableText`, `TextLayoutResult`, and `MultiParagraph` were written with the presumption that cursor placement was a major use case. And `getOffsetForPosition()` performs as expected in situations where you're placing a cursor.

They didn't seem to have much available for correcting this issue and I wasn't prepared to do any sophisticated geometry that I'm sure they've already handled somewhere I can't find. So I did the laziest thing possible.

I cut and pasted the original `ClickableText` and changed 3 lines.

```
@Composable
fun AltClickableText(
    text: AnnotatedString,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    style: TextStyle = TextStyle.Default,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    onClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val layoutResult = remember { mutableStateOf<TextLayoutResult?>(null) }
    val pressIndicator = Modifier.pointerInput(onClick) {
        detectTapGestures { pos ->
            layoutResult.value?.let { layoutResult ->
                val fuzzyHalfCharacterSize=layoutResult.getBoundingBox(0).width/2  //<-added
                val correctedPosition=pos-Offset(fuzzyHalfCharacterSize,0f) //<-added
                onClick(layoutResult.getOffsetForPosition(correctedPosition)) //<-modified
            }
        }
    }

    BasicText(
        text = text,
        modifier = modifier.then(pressIndicator),
        style = style,
        softWrap = softWrap,
        overflow = overflow,
        maxLines = maxLines,
        onTextLayout = {
            layoutResult.value = it
            onTextLayout(it)
        }
    )
}
```

I should warn you that while writing this, I learned that an object called `fuzzyHalfCharacterSize` is a part of the actual Android text API. That, whatever it is, is not what I am referring to. It is just a variable name. Presumably representing something extremely similar to theirs.